# Filter and delete items by comparing two arrays of objects with different elements

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have two arrays

```
arr1 = [{path: "path1"}, {path: "path2"}];
arr2 = [{path: "path1"}];
```

First, I want to find the element that is removed from arr1 (in this case its path1 object) by comparing two arrays and manipulate the first array or overwrite it by removing the item. In this case the expected array is

```
expArray = [{path: "path2"}]
```

I have tried using `array.filter` method.

```
var filteredElements = arr1 .filter(function(obj) {
    return !arr2 .some(function(obj2) {
        return obj.Path === obj2.Path;
    });    
});
```

But it only gives the list of element that are different, but does not support removing the element from the array. Is there a way to do this using underscore or traditional way ?

Comment: In short you want ({A} U {B}) - {B}, right?

Comment: Made this compare algo in C# for my parser. Very complex problem in general and in case both are not sorted, solution may be extremely slow. In case you have some limits - depth, size, etc. it should be a bit easier, but... Anyway this terrible algo from C# could be simply ported - have also IIFE port of iterators yet. In case you can check Gason fork on my Github (profile). There is also sort, which is much more complicated, so in case you do not sticked to JS, you can try that C# version.

Comment: @Tom: Yes, this is an `O(n^2)` algorithm, which might or might not be a problem depending upon the data.  And we can easily change this to an `O(n)` solution if it is a problem, just with a hashing function.  Here that's trivial, since we can hash with only `obj.path`, but it might be much harder in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo of `Path` vs `path`. The code works with this change.

```js
var arr1 = [{ path: "path1" }, { path: "path2" }],
    arr2 = [{ path: "path1" }],
    filteredElements = arr1.filter(function(obj) {
        return !arr2.some(function(obj2) {
            return obj.path === obj2.path;
            //         ^             ^
        });
    });
    
console.log(filteredElements);
```

If you like to mutate `arr1` you could splice unwanted elements and because this changes the length, you could iterate from the end.

```js
var arr1 = [{ path: "path1" }, { path: "path2" }],
    arr2 = [{ path: "path1" }],
    i = arr1.length;

while (i--) {
    if (arr2.some(({ path }) => arr1[i].path === path)) {
        arr1.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array#splice` to remove the element from an existing array.

```js
let arr1 = [{ path: "path1" }, {  path: "path2"}];

let arr2 = [{ path: "path1" }];

// get length of array for iteration
let l = arr1.length;

// iterate from end to start to avoid skipping index after removing an element
while (l--) {
  // check elemnt present in the array
  if (arr2.some(obj => obj.path === arr1[l].path))
    // remove the element
    arr1.splice(l, 1);
}
console.log(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just typed the `path` property as `Path` and it is returning an empty array.

The code working:

```
var arr1 = [{path: "path1"}, {path: "path2"}];
var arr2 = [{path: "path1"}];

var filteredElements = arr1.filter(function(obj) {
  return !arr2.some(function(obj2) {
    return obj.path === obj2.path;
  });
});
```

If you want to overwrite the first array, just replace `filteredElements` by `arr1`.

Comment: I would like to delete the filtered elements from the arr1 itself

Answer (score 0):

you can use map,

```js
let arr1 = [{ path: "path1" }, {  path: "path2"}];
const arr2 = [{ path: "path1" }];

const itemsToRemove = arr2.map(a => a.path);
arr1 = arr1.filter(a => !itemsToRemove.includes(a.path));
console.log(arr1);
```

filter and reassign the array values.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to  handle this is to separate the logic for testing whether two items are equal from the process of filtering the data.  Here, `keep` is a very simple higher-order function.  We pass it a function that reports whether two object have the same `path` property and get back a function on two arrays.

We then simply use that function.

```js
const keep = (eq) => (xs, ys) =>
  xs.filter ( x => ys .some ( y => eq(x, y) ) )

const keepByPath = keep ( (x, y) => x.path == y.path )

const arr1 = [{ path: "path1", foo: 1 }, { path: "path2", foo: 2 }]
const arr2 = [{ path: "path1", bar: 1 }]

console.log (
  keepByPath (arr1, arr2) //~> [{ path: "path1", foo: 1 }]
)
```

Note that I added some properties.  These demonstrate that we keep only items from the first array.